# Is it possible to add more columns to a DataGrid when AutogenerateColumns==True?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Simply put, I have a `DataGrid` in my XML file that I bound to a list - in this example, a list of `Person`s. However, I also want an extra column, as all entries in this list are going to be a subclass of `Person`, i.e. `PersonWithAge`. I am not allowed to change the type of `ListOfPeople`, though.

If I add the column in XAML manually, it crashes right away. How can I add this columns and synchronise it with all the rest? Is there some way to cast it within the XAML file? Or can one be added in the `m_grid_AutoGeneratingColumn` method?

This is my code:

```
// In MyGridView.xaml.cs
public class MyGridView
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> ListOfPeople { get; set; }

    private void m_grid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) 
    {
        /* Some formatting here... */
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonWithAge : Person
{
    public int Age{ get; set; }
}
```

And the XAML code:

```
// MyGridView.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="Project.MyGridView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>    
         <DataGrid Name="m_myGrid" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPeople}
                   AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="m_grid_AutoGeneratingColumn" >
                <!--DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" /-->  <!-- This makes the thing crash -->
         </DataGrid >
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: OK you cannot change ListOfPeople but can you create a new list.  Public IEnumerable<PersonWithAge> ListOfPeopleWithAge { get { return ListOfPeople.OfType<PersonWithAge>(); } }

Comment: I see your idea, but a `ObservableCollection` doesn't seem to have that `OfType` method, does it?

Comment: But if there were a way to cast it from the one to the other, that would be brilliant. But simply casting gives me this error: `Cannot convert type 'ObservableCollection<Project.Person>' to 'ObservableCollection<Project.PersonWithAge>'`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx  OfType is LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move columns you are adding in `DataGrid.Columns`

```
    <DataGrid Name="m_myGrid" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPeople}
               AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="m_grid_AutoGeneratingColumn" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid >
```

Comment: Not bad, that works partially! Although this way, the column doesn't yet have a Binding to the `Age` property. Can you access that in this way?

Comment: offcourse , just bind it to Age property, your item contains the Age property, even if it derived it contains the Age property.

Comment: Whauh, that actually works! I had no idea you could do that. I expected some compile time error because the `Age` wouldn't be visible, but it doesn't care and works fine. :-)